# Observable<Type> | async does not return null

Tags: angular, observable, async.js, angular11

nav.component.html:

```
<div class="dropdown" *ngIf="currentUser$ | async" dropdown>
 // some div inside
</div>
```

nav.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
  model: any = {}
  currentUser$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('nav.component onInit');
    this.currentUser$ = this.accountService.currentUser$;
    console.log(this.currentUser$);
  }
}
```

account.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from '../_models/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = 'https://localhost:5001/api/';
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
}
```

I am learning the observable concept and faced a problem that when refreshing a page without any data stored in local storage, it looks like my currentUser$ is still not null.

You probably noticed that in my nav.component.ts I have a log and every time I refresh a page or delete a local storage data I still have the following object:

[print screen of the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzx4H.png)